# How to export a math formula with a beautiful, high resolution font for a tattoo?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, export

I'd like to a make a math based tattoo with the Euler's formula for `i^i`:

```
i^i=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}
k\in\mathbb{Z}
```

[image]

[image]

I'm looking for a way to export the formula with a beautiful font, good size and high quality resolution. Also, for a way to combine both sentences in a good way.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: do you really want the double struck ⅈ and ⅇ ? Apart from mathematica I don't think I've ever seen them used in practice?

Comment: your question isn't really very clear, (almost) all fonts available to TeX are scalable type1 or opentype fonts so size and resolution are not involved, you can print any pdf at whatever size you like. So the only question is a "beautiful font" which is highly subjective and has no answer. (there is a network wide "close question" mechanism for such subjective questions)

Comment: Also, you need to define "export".  Does this mean produce a PDF?  Or print on a piece of paper in large size?  Also, a better way to phrase your question would be for you to decide on a "beautiful font", and ask how to use it to get the formula shown in a size that you specify.

Comment: There's nothing special to do. I used LaTeXiT on my Mac to render the generalized Stokes theorem at something like 36 point type, printed it, and took it to the tattoo artist, who said it was a perfect template. (The tattoo turned out fantastic too.)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?  Also check out [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive?lang=en).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\adjustbox{scale=5}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
$\displaystyle i^i= e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}$\\
$\displaystyle k\in\mathbb{Z}$
\end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

Most PDF printer drivers also have scaling options.