# How to define the height of text in cm

Tags: fonts, fontsize, math-fonts, textheight

I know the question I am going to ask is similar to others posted here. However, I still can not find the right answer. I have checked:

[How to export a math formula with a beautiful, high resolution font for a tattoo?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610931/how-to-export-a-math-formula-with-a-beautiful-high-resolution-font-for-a-tattoo)

[What measure in the text is it that is the font size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154602/what-measure-in-the-text-is-it-that-is-the-font-size)

[What is the local height of a capital letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275374/what-is-the-local-height-of-a-capital-letter/275381#275381)

[\settoheight is slightly shorter than actual height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544253/settoheight-is-slightly-shorter-than-actual-height)

Down to business, I want to get a tattoo with Eulers' identity. So I want to be sure of the height of the text.

And basically that is my question, how to set the height of the text to a specific height (in this case probably fron the baseline to the ascender) in cm, say 1 cm.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[red,line width = 1mm] (0,0)--node[color=black,left](T) { \adjustbox{scale=3}{
$\displaystyle e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0$
}} (0,1cm);
\draw[red] (0,0)--(-6cm,0);
\draw[red] (0,1)--++(-6cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I am getting approx. the height I want, but basically I am just working around the problem for the solution, instead of doing it right. I draw a vertical line of height 1 cm, and two other horizontal lines, on the base and upper part. Then, after tweaking around with the value of the scale in the adjust box, I get something similar to what I am looking for.
[image]

But once again, Is there any other way (direct, efficient, or simple better) to get the desire result?

Thanks in advance for your contribution!

Editing 1:
I have one additional question: In either my solution as with the @pascal974 s, the plus sign is lower than the baseline.
Is there a way to move up the + such that it stays above the baseline?

[image]

I tried by wrapping the + sign in scriptstyle:

```
$e^{i \pi}\, {\scriptstyle + } \,1 = 0$
```

But this command just makes the sign smaller, placing it a the same "ground".
[image]

Cheers!

Comment: There is `\resizebox{!}{1cm}{...}` from either the adjustbox or graphicx packages (it moves around).  It can still be fooled by white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With {adjustbox}{totalheight=..} 3cm in my example.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}
    \newcommand{\h}{3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw,inner sep =0pt] at (0,0){%
    \begin{adjustbox}{totalheight=\h}
            $e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0$
    \end{adjustbox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\rule{1mm}{\h}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have just one additional question: In the equation, the plus-sign is lower than the baseline. Is there a way to move up the + such that it stays above the baseline?

Comment: I don't really like it but by tinkering

$e^{i \pi}\,\raisebox{1pt}{+}\,1\,\raisebox{1pt}{=}\,0$
or
$e^{i \pi}\,\tikz\node {$+$};\,1=0$

Comment: or $e^{i \pi}\,\scalebox{0.8}{\tikz\node {$+$};}\,1=0$...

Comment: thanks for your help. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In plain TeX, you can divide 1 cm by the height of your formula and apply the quotient (times 1000) as `\magnification`:

```tex
\dimen0=1cm
\setbox0=\hbox{$e^{i\pi}+1=0$}
\dimen1=\ht0 \advance\dimen1 by\dp0
\count0=\dimen0 \multiply\count0 by 1000
\count1=\dimen1 \divide\count0 by\count1
\magnification=\count0
\box0
\bye
```

(Rounding errors are smaller than tattooing errors.)

Comment: Theissen: Thanks for your contribution, however, I have no idea how to use/type/work with plain TeX, I use Latex in overleaf. 
I tried the your code inside the \begin{document} ... \end{document}. But it gives errors.

Comment: You can [run plain TeX in Overleaf](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Can_I_run_plain_TeX_on_Overleaf%3F), see https://www.overleaf.com/project/6208c7d937b30316dc2ad6d2